# Using Nutch to crawl a specified URL list

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

I have one million URL list to fetch. I use this list as nutch seeds and use the basic **crawl** command of Nutch to fetch them. However, I find that Nutch automatically fetches not-on-list URLs. I do set the crawl parameters as -depth 1 -topN 1000000. But it does not work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this property in `nutch-site.xml`. (by default its true so it adds outlinks to the crawldb)

```
<property>
  <name>db.update.additions.allowed</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, updatedb will add newly discovered URLs, if false
  only already existing URLs in the CrawlDb will be updated and no new
  URLs will be added.
  </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Delete the crawl and urls directory (if created before)
- Create and Update the seed file ( where URLs are listed 1URL per row)
- Restart the crawling process

**Command**

```
nutch crawl urllist -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 1000000
```

- urllist  - Directory where seed file (url list) is present
- crawl    - Directory name

Even if the problem persists, try to delete your nutch folder and restart the whole process.

Comment: I do not want Nutch to crawl outlinks from the seeds, but just the URLs I give as seeds.